# Newsletter subscribe/unsubscribe email notification event observer

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, newsletter-subscriber

I am writing my own admin email notifications module.

So far it has New Order and Low Stock observers set up and working just fine.

I want to add the Newsletter subscribe/unsubscribe observer to it and what I have works fine but when changing newsletter subscription status of a Customer (by saving the Customer in dashboard) it seems to send notification emails twice (first with current subscription status and then for new changed one ... for example if I change customer from Subscribed to Unsubscribed it will send email that there is new subscriber then email that subscriber has been unsubscribed

**Observer**

```
<?php
namespace Hapex\AdminEmailNotifications\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Hapex\AdminEmailNotifications\Helper\Data;
use Hapex\AdminEmailNotifications\Helper\Email;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;

class NewsletterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $date;

    protected $helperData;

    protected $helperEmail;

    protected $messageManager;


    public function __construct(
        DateTime $date,
        Data $helperData,
        Email $helperEmail,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
        $this->helperEmail = $helperEmail;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $event = $observer->getEvent();
            $subscriber = $event->getSubscriber();
            $enable = $this->helperData->isEnabled();
            if ($enable)
            {
                $subscriberStatus = $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus();
                // subscriberStatus = 1 subscribe
                // subscriberStatus = 3 unsubscribed
                if ($subscriberStatus == '1'  && $this->helperData->isNewsletterSubscribeEnabled())
                {
                    $this->sendMailNewsletterSubscribe($subscriber);
                }
                else if ($subscriberStatus == '3' && $this->helperData->isNewsletterUnsubscribeEnabled())
                {
                    $this->sendMailNewsletterUnsubscribe($subscriber);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("Error : " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function sendMailNewsletterSubscribe($subscriber)
    {
        try {
            $storeId = $subscriber->getStoreId();
            $email = $subscriber->getEmail();
            $receivers = $this->helperData->getNewsletterReceivers($storeId);
            $emailTemplate = $this->helperData->getNewsletterSubscribeEmailTemplate($storeId);
            $templateVar = ['varEmail' => 'Email: '.$email,];
            $this->helperEmail->sendEmail($receivers, $emailTemplate, $templateVar, $storeId);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("Error : " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function sendMailNewsletterUnsubscribe($subscriber)
    {
        try {
            $storeId = $subscriber->getStoreId();
            $email = $subscriber->getEmail();
            $receivers = $this->helperData->getNewsletterReceivers($storeId);
            $emailTemplate = $this->helperData->getNewsletterUnsubscribeEmailTemplate($storeId);
            $templateVar = ['varEmail' => 'Email: '.$email,];
            $this->helperEmail->sendEmail($receivers, $emailTemplate, $templateVar, $storeId);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("Error : " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Event**

```
<event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_after">
        <observer name="hapex_newsletter_observer" instance="Hapex\AdminEmailNotifications\Observer\NewsletterObserver" />
    </event>
```

Is there a good way to maybe save the status before the event triggered then take it in the observer and if it has changed do its thing so it will fire only once ... any other way to make so it doesn't fire twice on Customer update?

Thanks

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: unfortunately, nope :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin for this, like I have created a plugin where only when customer get unsubscribe from frontend then I have added some customization, for this I have added plugin for

```
Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber
```

Class's `unsubscribe()` method with **after** plugin
My code is, In di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Nerdsinn_Queue_Plugin_Magento_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber" sortOrder="10" type="Nerdsinn\Queue\Plugin\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber"/>
    </type>
```

and then in `/Nerdsinn/Queue/Plugin/Magento/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`

```
namespace Nerdsinn\Queue\Plugin\Magento\Newsletter\Model;

/**
 * Class Subscriber
 *
 * @package Nerdsinn\Queue\Plugin\Magento\Newsletter\Model
 */
class Subscriber
{

    public function afterUnsubscribe(
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        //Your plugin code
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Here on $result you can getData() to access available data